# javascript: is there a way to play audio in a mobile browser while the phone is locked? (chrome/safari)

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

I have a web application that asks the user to queue inline. The user has to click a button in order to queue. Once the administrator of the website 'calls' the user, audio will be played in the user's browser (in real-time). This is done using a WebSocket connection.

The problem is, after the user joins a queue, the user can minimize the browser and lock his phone while waiting to be called. Once the administrator calls the user, the audio does not play until the user opens/restores the browser again.

This is the whole scenario:

1. User visits the website
2. Clicks the "Queue" button
3. Minimizes the browser and lock the phone
4. Administrator calls the user
5. User does not know he is called until he opens the browser again

This is how I call the user:

```
this.$socket.client.emit("callCustomer", {
   socketId: <socket_id>
})
```

And this is how the user receives the event:

```
this.$socket.client.on("callCustomer", async function () {
    // play audio here
})
```

Is there a way I can trigger `this.$socket.client.on("callCustomer")` and play the audio while the user's phone is locked?

Comment: I believe this is only possible when you build an actual app that allows background processes and/or notifications on the phone. Some mobile browsers allow push notifications, or you could look into mobile browser extensions.